# Data lost in Progress bar on moving to new tab in magento checkout

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout, tabs, onepage-checkout

My requirement is to customize the Onepage checkout process and adding a new step between the “Payment Information” and “Review” Steps.

So I followed the following instruction.

http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/adding-step-onepage-checkout

[image]

But after following this,  my new tab is displayed on One Step Checkout Page. But When i click to my custom tab, the Side Bar that display Checkout progress is not showing any information it showed previously.

Please Help me.

Comment: Using a layout update in your module you need to add the additional step to:
app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/checkout/onepage/progress.phtml

Comment: What happens in your JavaScript if you set the final parameter of the goToSection call. `this.gotoSection('your_step', true);`

Comment: @DavidManners I have overridden onepagecontroller.php to move to sections.

Comment: @DavidManners this is what I get in my console {"goto_section":"exempt"}.exempt is the name of my new block

Comment: In the JS for your new step have you included any extra JS that could re draw the information in the sidebar ? Without looking more into your customisations I would consider stepping through the JS in chrome dev tools to see what could be manipulating that section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with the checkout.steps variable in the checkout.initialize method. You should add your custom step to the array of steps like so:`checkout.steps = ["login", "billing", "shipping", "shipping_method", "payment","customtab", "review"]`